# What are the exact effects and formulas for high and low morale?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

In previous Heroes games, I believe the [formula for good morale](http://mightandmagic.wikia.com/wiki/Morale) was something like +10% chance of a second turn per positive point of morale.  But [some mention](http://www.celestialheavens.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12695) that morale was debuffed for Heroes 6.  I also couldn't seem to find the formula in the community created player's manual.

What is the exact formula for getting good and bad morale effects and what are the exact effects that can occur due to good or bad Morale?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, your morale stat is expressed simply as a percent chance of a morale effect.  Positive morale gives a second turn at "half strength" i.e. half movement and half strength attack.  Negative morale forces the unit to miss its turn entirely.  So if you have a +28 morale, you will have a 28% chance of gaining a half move/attack.  There can be other situational effects of good morale, such as the Haven faction's ability bar filling up, or triggering additional turns of persistent effects like regeneration.

Comment: +1, I'm not sure if your right or not, because I'm haven't been playing it lately.  But if no one else responds or disagrees with your answer, I'll try and remember to select your answer.